# map function is not working properly with Dataframe(toDF)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I am running below code as Dataset (`toDS`) it is working fine but when I am converting it to Dataframe (`toDF`), it is not working with Dataframe.

**Dataset Code:**

```
val primitiveDS = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDS()    
primitiveDS.map(_ + 1).collect() 
// **Output** : Array(2, 3, 4)
```

**Dataframe Code:**

```
val primitiveDF = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF()
primitiveDF.map(_ + 1).collect()
```

**Error**:

```
scala> primitiveDF.map(_ + 1).collect()
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
       primitiveDF.map(_ + 1).collect()
                       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map over a DataFrame, your elements will be of type `Row` (kind of a untyped collection), you cant just add 1 to a Row, instead you must extract the element from the row first using an accessor method like `.getInt`:

```
primitiveDF.map((r: Row) => r.getInt(0) + 1).collect()
```

or shorter :

```
primitiveDF.map(_.getInt(0) + 1).collect()
```

or with pattern-matching :

```
primitiveDF.map{case Row(i:Int) => i+1}.collect()
```